# RMAN Control File backup failed. [ORA-00245: control file backup failed;]

Tags: oracle, rman

I have daily backup on my Oracle 12c database on linux. My RMAN failed to take backup control file. But not every day. Its failed 1 or 2 time in a week. Database and archivelog backup is fine. My control file is on shared location.

SQL> show parameter control_file;

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
control_file_record_keep_time        integer     7
control_files                        string      +CREDOLOG1/TB/CONTROLFILE/c
                                                 urrent.256.978479201, +CREDOLO
                                                 G2/TB/CONTROLFILE/current.2
                                                 56.978479201
```

It give this error when failed.

```
channel t1: starting piece 1 at 02-DEC-22
channel t1: finished piece 1 at 02-DEC-22
piece handle=/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/02_DEC_2022/DB_BACKUP/RMAN.TB.DB.L0.20221202.s01ebetl_1_1.bk tag=FULL_BK_DISK_02_DEC_2022 comment=NONE
channel t1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:26:45
channel t1: starting compressed incremental level 0 datafile backup set
channel t1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on t1 channel at 12/02/2022 04:54:26
ORA-00245: control file backup failed; in Oracle RAC, target might not be on shared storage
continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
channel t1: starting compressed incremental level 0 datafile backup set
channel t1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
including current SPFILE in backup set
channel t1: starting piece 1 at 02-DEC-22
channel t1: finished piece 1 at 02-DEC-22
piece handle=/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/02_DEC_2022/DB_BACKUP/RMAN.TB.DB.L0.20221202.s21ebgg2_1_1.bk tag=FULL_BK_DISK_02_DEC_2022 comment=NONE
channel t1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:01
channel t2: finished piece 1 at 02-DEC-22
piece handle=/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/02_DEC_2022/DB_BACKUP/RMAN.TB.DB.L0.20221202.rv1ebe7i_1_1.bk tag=FULL_BK_DISK_02_DEC_2022 comment=NONE
channel t2: backup set complete, elapsed time: 01:31:14
released channel: t1
released channel: t2
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================

RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on t1 channel at 12/02/2022 04:54:26
ORA-00245: control file backup failed; in Oracle RAC, target might not be on shared storage

RMAN>
```

Below is my RMAN script. Please advise me

```
run {
CROSSCHECK ARCHIVELOG ALL;
CROSSCHECK BACKUP;
allocate channel ch1 type disk format '/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/${timestamp}/DB_BACKUP/RMAN.%d.DB.L0.%T.%U.bk' maxpiecesize 50g;
allocate channel ch2 type disk format '/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/${timestamp}/DB_BACKUP/RMAN.%d.DB.L0.%T.%U.bk' maxpiecesize 50g;
backup as compressed backupset incremental level = 0 database tag = full_bk_disk_${timestamp};
release channel ch1;
release channel ch2;
allocate channel ch3 type disk format '/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/${timestamp}/ARCHIVELOG/RMAN.%d.ARC.L0.%T.%U.bk';
backup archivelog until time 'sysdate -2' delete input;
sql  'alter system archive log current';
backup archivelog all not backed up 1 times format '/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/${timestamp}/ARCHIVELOG/RMAN.%d.ARC.L0.%T.%U.bk';
backup current controlfile format '/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/${timestamp}/CONTROLFILE/RMAN.%d.CTRL.%T.%U.bk';
backup spfile format '/RMAN_BACKUP/PRO_CORE/FULL_BACKUP/${timestamp}/SPFILE/RMAN.%d.SPFILE.%T.%U.bk';
#delete noprompt obsolete;
delete noprompt expired backup;
release channel ch3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical error on RAC with the default value of snapshot controlfile location.

The problem is not the controlfile location, but the location of the snapshot controlfile. Check its current value:

```
rman target /
show all;
```

Then configure it to a shared to location, for example:

```
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '+CREDOLOG1/TB/snapcf_TB.f';
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it.